# How can I retrieve the output of an outputstream

Tags: java, sockets, outputstream

I'm well aware that outputstreams are only meant for writing data. But I want to retrieve its own output and I know out has protected access in FilterOutputStream. Is there a loop or a shortcut that I can do to get the .out field of an output stream ?

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost,4000);
DataOutputStream Data = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
Data.writeUTF("Hi");
System.out.println(Data.out); // What I want to achieve.
```

Comment: I have a nasty suspicion there's a very strong [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. Can you give more details about what you're trying to achieve by doing what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: A chat program. But I don't want to deal with the loops of listening to the inputstream.

Comment: Is there any Error using the Method you have in the question? Perhaps give more details.

Comment: What do you mean by "its own output"? `Data.out` stores a reference to the socket's OutputStream. If you want to get that, you could just call `socket.getOutputStream()`.

Comment: But when you tell System.out.println(socket.getOutputStream()); it returns the actual object not the written data.

Comment: Be a terrible person and use reflection to access your ``Data`` variable's ``out`` field.

Comment: @SamuelMusa Well `System.out.println(Data.out)` would also print the actual object not the written data...

Answer (score 1):

To get the `out` field, you could derive a subclass of DataOutputStream and make the output stream publicly retrievable:

```
class YourDataOutputStream extends DataOutputStream {
    public OutputStream getOut() {
        return out;
    }
}
```

However, if what you really want to do is capture the data that is sent out over the socket, this will not do what you want, since it will just return the output stream object returned by the socket.  You could, however, write a subclass of FilterOutputStream that overrides the write() methods to print out the data coming through, or store it in an array or file, before writing the data to the underlying output stream.  The override methods would look something like:

```
public void write(int dataByte) {
    System.out.println(dataByte);
    out.write(dataByte);
}
```

You would then construct an instance of this class on the socket's output stream, and construct the DataOutputStream on the instance of this class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `org.apache.commons.io.output.TeeOutputStream`:

```
OutputStream out1 = socket.getOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream out2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new TeeOutputStream (out1, out2));
out.writeUTF("Hi");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(out2.toByteArray()));
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what he is really looking for, but he doen't know it. I think he really wants to propagate a single write to all chat clients. A set of nested TeeOutputStreams attached to all the socket output streams will do that, i.e. `new TeeOutputStream(new TeeOutputStream(socket1.getOutputStream(), socket2.getOutputStream()), socket3.getOutputStream())` and so on.

Comment: TeeInputStream is bad idea for chat. If one client connection hangs all chat will hang. It is necessary use one thread per client in case of blocking IO.

Comment: Did someone mention `TeeInputStream`? All I can see is a `TeeOutputStream.` The blocking problem in that comes essentially from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost,4000);
DataOutputStream Data = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
Data.writeUTF("Hi");
System.out.println(Data.out); // What I want to achieve
```

'What [you] want to achieve' is entirely equivalent to

```
System.out.println(socket.getOutputStream());
```

It is also completely pointless. It will only print something like `java.net.SocketOutputStream@.....`. Not the 'contents', i.e. what has been written.